# Can an Indonesian citizen visit South Korea without a visa?

Tags: visas, south-korea, visa-free-entry, us-residents, indonesian-citizens

I'll be going round trip (USA-Indonesia) and transit in South Korea. I have a US green card. I want to stop by in South Korea for 1 week. I think I don't need a visa, but I'm not sure.
I will have to apply for K-ETA, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re good without a visa, you can check your actual itinerary via [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/page/travelinformation/2616013641/modify.htm)

Visa Exemptions:

> Nationals of Indonesia with an entry visa issued by Australia, Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 30 days. They must:

- arrive from a third country and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 30 days to the country that issued the visa; or
- arrive from the country that issued the visa and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 30 days.
  The entry visa must be in the form of visa sticker on the passport, except for Australian visas. If passengers have a transit point before arriving in Korea (Rep.) or after leaving Korea (Rep.), the maximum stay in that transit country must be within 3 days.

> Nationals of Indonesia with a residence permit issued by USA for a maximum stay of 30 days. They must:

- arrive from a third country and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 30 days to the country that issued the residence permit; or
- arrive from the country that issued the residence permit and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 30 days.
  If passengers have a transit point before arriving in Korea (Rep.) or after leaving Korea (Rep.), the maximum stay in that transit country must be within 3 days.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I don't need a visa.  I read that to enter Korea either by using a visa or K-ETA.  So If I don't need a visa, I have to fill in K-ETA.  One of the question in K-ETA is 'Select the Citizenship/Nationality shown on the passport'.  Indonesia is NOT on the list.  What should I do? I can't fill in K-ETA?

Comment: @user144951 Try [contacting K-ETA](https://www.k-eta.go.kr/portal/board/viewemailcontact.do) and/or [the Embassy or Consulate of the Republic of Korea located in your jurisdiction](https://www.k-eta.go.kr/portal/board/viewboardlist.do?tmpltNm=faq) for advice